# Excel column comparison if column 1 equal to value find maximum in column 2

Tags: excel

I have a problem with Excel functions and need to find a certain value when column 1 is equal to a value i need to find Another maximum value in Another column. To narrow the problem down:

Column 1 equals certain value 
then column 2 is maximum

Here is a fraction of the data to compare

[image: Excel table]

Comment: Look into MAXIFS()

Comment: my version of Excel doesn't equip that function